# Android 4.3. Gap between scrollBar and right border

Tags: android

Here my xml layout: TabLayout with ViewPager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/standard_min_height_container"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchView"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget" />

    <ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/customViewPager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/common_color_bg"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here result on Androd 5.0+

[image: android 6]

And here result on Android 4.3

[image: gap]

Why on Androdi 4.3. has gap between right border and scrollBar?
I need to show scrollBar to be align right. Like on Android 5.0+

Answer (score 1):

You should change the scrollbarStyle to the one you want.

android:scrollbarStyle:

```
 insideInset    //Inside the padding and inset.
 insideOverlay //Inside the padding and overlaid.
 outsideInset //Edge of the view and inset.
 outsideOverlay //Edge of the view and overlaid.
```

Check this out 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbarStyle